# Symbol identification - right arrow with line through it

Tags: probability, notation, machine-learning, control-theory

I was hoping someone could tell me what the right-arrow with a line through it means in this equation (the parameter of the P() function).

[image: Equation for a performance index]

The equation is from the book "deep reinforcemnt learning" by Mohit Sewak.

Thank you in advance,

DB

Comment: Equations without context do not mean much in general as notations are not only field dependent but also author-dependent. You have provided a source but not exactly where this equation is written. What page?

Comment: Sorry about that. It's equation 10.4 on page 133 which is a reformulation of equation 10.2.

Comment: The double right arrow is a common symbol for "implies": $\implies$. Crossing a symbol with a slanted line is a common means of denoting negation. So the most likely interpretation is "$\tau$ does not imply $\theta$". But without knowing anything about $\tau$ or $\theta$, I cannot say whether that interpretation makes sense. I would guess it means the probability that event $\tau$ occurs but event $\theta$ does not.